# Adding simple point robots in drake

Tags: drake

I have been following the [point_finger.ipynb](https://deepnote.com/workspace/Manipulation-ac8201a1-470a-4c77-afd0-2cc45bc229ff/project/87d8044f-3eb2-4f25-b52f-f51a5eca68b7/notebook/point_finger-c961c7f9eeef4aabb2eda47833464013) tutorial to add a point finger robot in my own simulation. The idea of adding joints between the finger and the world and then actuating these joints makes complete sense. However, I have been struggling with understanding the purpose of the `false_body1` in the code. I am pasting in relevant bit here

```
def AddPointFinger(plant):
    finger = AddShape(plant, Sphere(0.01), "finger", color=[0.9, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0])
    false_body1 = plant.AddRigidBody(
        "false_body1",
        finger,
        SpatialInertia(0, [0, 0, 0], UnitInertia(0, 0, 0)),
    )
    finger_x = plant.AddJoint(
        PrismaticJoint(
            "finger_x",
            plant.world_frame(),
            plant.GetFrameByName("false_body1"),
            [1, 0, 0],
            -0.3,
            0.3,
        )
    )
    plant.AddJointActuator("finger_x", finger_x)
    finger_z = plant.AddJoint(
        PrismaticJoint(
            "finger_z",
            plant.GetFrameByName("false_body1"),
            plant.GetFrameByName("finger"),
            [0, 0, 1],
            0.0,
            0.5,
        )
    )
    finger_z.set_default_translation(0.25)
    plant.AddJointActuator("finger_z", finger_z)

    return finger
```

Maybe I am not understanding something here, but what do both prismatic joints have different parent frames?

Thank you for help and instruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is the nature of actuation that Drake's `MultibodyPlant` currently affords. You can only actuate 1-dof joints. You'll note that the joint between  false_body1 and world has its axis in the Wx direction and the joint between false_body1 and fingers has its axis in the Wz direction. This gives you two degrees of freedom for the finger: in the Wx and Wz directions.

If you wanted to actuate complete 6-dof robot, you'd continue the pattern by adding more intermediate, massless bodies joined with a third prismatic joint and three revolute joints.

Comment: Ah I see, does that mean we can get by by adding joints to randomly declared Frames. Why is there a requirement for a `false_body1`. The `finger` seems to actually be shape. I guess I find it confusing that the `x` prismatic-joint was added between the `world_origin` and a `body_origin`, and the `z` prismatic-joint was added between a `body_origin` and a `shape`. What is the right way to think about adding and actuating joints in `drake`?

Comment: A joint connects two bodies. (Even a floating joint "connects" a body to the world.) So, you need to think of a kinematic chain where each joint in the chain gives your terminal body one more degree of freedom. In order to only reason about the dynamics properties of the end body, all of the intermediate bodies become massless. That way they effect the kinematics, but not the dynamics. I'm not sure what you mean by `body_origin` and `shape` (those names don't appear in the sample code in your original question).

Comment: continued... the `AddShape()` function is a convenience wrapper that adds a body to the plant and associates some geometry with it. But, what it returns, is a "model instance index". We use it so that the massless body `false_body1` will be added to the same model instance. The name is, perhaps, a bit misleading.